# Print to file using enscript

Tags: macos, unix, printing

I want to print to file using the unix command `enscript`. I've looked in the man pages but can't figure out how to get it to print to file without it going straight to the printer.

Thanks

Comment: Are you on OSX or on Unix? The `enscript` implementations are likely different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the Unix Man page](http://www.gis.usu.edu/unix/man/enscript.shtml):

> -p file, --output=file
>
> Leave output to file file . If file is `-', leave output to stdout .

Thus:

```
 enscript  [formatting options] -p output_file input_file
```